# Jquery toggleClass not working applying to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to apply a toggleClass but it isn't applying the new class.
What's going on?

```
<a href="#" id="cf_onclick">Click</a> 
<div id="main" class="invisible">
Hi there            
</div> 

.invisible{
   opacity: 0;

}
.visible{
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
  $("#main").toggleClass("visible");
});
});
```

Here's the jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Gilgamesh415/grxQX/17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean your fiddle, you forgot to add `jQuery` library, in the top left of the jsfiddle window.

Check [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/grxQX/1/)

If you mean your website check you have the jQuery library loaded by adding `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` inside you head tags.

Comment: @LineyHamilton, did you added the jQuery library on your page?

Comment: @LineyHamilton, ok. Good! Please accept the answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#s").click(function(){

$("#main").toggleClass("n");
});
});
</script>



<div id="main" class="m"></div>
<button id="s">click</button>

<style type="text/css">
    .m
{ opacity:0;}
.n
{
 width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:2px solid yellow;
    background:green; 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 3s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 1;   
}
</style>
```

demo here:http://jsfiddle.net/65Hg4/1/

Answer (score 0):

And try using a self invoking anonymous function:

```
(function(){
.... //your code
}(jQuery));
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){...});
```

Since best practice is to load the scripts at the bottom of your page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, you don't need to check if the document has been loaded ($(document).ready()), it already has.

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/micka/94pNW/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cf_onclick").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  $("#main").toggleClass("invisible").toggleClass("visible");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/grxQX/18/